# Where are built-in methods of django model manager defined in source code?

Tags: django

By default, django model's default manager **`objects`** has below built-in methods:

```
all(), filter(), exclude(), get(), create(), order_by()
```

But I did not find where are those methods defined in Django source code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query methods are in `db/models/query.py`:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/query.py#L966